# Flipkart or Snapdeal like Payment Method in nopCommerce 3.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, e-commerce, nopcommerce, payment-processing, payment-method

I'm developing an e-Commerce site with nopCommerce 3.5. I have CCAVENUE payment gateway provided by my client.

the problem is, at OnePageCheckOut, I want to implement payment options like Flipkart or snapdeal or any other well known eCommerce site but don't know how to do it.

Currently it shows only 2 options as **COD & CCAvenue** but what i want to show is something like following image

For e.g. here's a screen shot of "payment method" selection implemented by by Snapdeal

[image: Payment Method]

Can any one help with this plz?

Comment: to which payment gateway you want to integrate?

Answer (score 0):

You can see a list of available plugins at http://www.nopcommerce.com/extensions-and-themes.aspx?category=2&pageindex=2 or

you can create your own payment NopCommerce plugin by taking help from [here](http://docs.nopcommerce.com/display/nc/How+to+write+a+nopCommerce+plugin)

Comment: i think you got me wrong. i know this stuff but here, i'm talking about OnePageCheckout page where the steps are mentioned like "1. Billing Address, 2. Shipping Address, 3. Payment Method, 4. Payment Info, 5. Confirm Order" etc. and in "Payment Method" i want to implement something like shown in above image.

Answer (score 0):

you can load IFrame of the CCAvenue direct in the PaymentInfo page of the CCAvenue plugin. This type of payment gateway is provided directly by CCAvenue when you load IFrame in payment info page. Ask CCAvenue team to activate all features like Net Banking, Debit Card, Credit Card etc

You have to activate only one payment gateway i.e CCAvenue 
It will directly load payment gateway without giving such a options like COD or CCAvenue.

Comment: Yeah, you're right Krutal and really, it's v. much helpful. But what if i want COD also along with CCAvenue options?

Comment: You can activate COD feature of the CCAvenue payment gateway. That's it !!

Comment: ohh.. thx.. let me impleent it that way.. will revert nd mark it as answer if i get succeed.. otherwise... discussion runs ahead.. :)